# Manually resolving AJAX return with promise

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to grasp my head around promises, and it looked simple. I imagined them as asynchronous vars. One of the problem I needed to resolve was making several AJAX calls which all needed to be resolved successfully, chaining them one after another, aka I need to make them synchronous to get the result. As making ajax call `sync: false` is deprecated I tried to make AJAX synchronous with promises.

```
     $.when(
          ajaxCall(param1),
          ajaxCall(param2)
     ).then(
        function(data) {
          console.log(['OK: ',data]);
        }, function() {
          console.log('Error');
        }
     ).fail(function () {
        console.log('Fail');
     });
```

And ajax call function is defined as:

```
ajaxCall: function ($id) {

        $.ajax({

             url: 'some_url'
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: "JSON",
             data: packed,

             success: function (data) {

                 var deferred = $.Deferred();
                 switch (data.code) {
                     case 200:
                         deferred.resolve(data);
                         break;
                     default:
                         deferred.reject(data);
                         break;
                 }

                 return deferred.promise();

             },
             error: function () {
                 $.Deferred().reject();
             }
         });

     }
```

I directly made some false ajax calls, but the .fail branch was never executed, and I am not sure what the problem is.
If I change `.then` to `.done`, then at least Error callback is executed, but no mater what I tried, I never reached Fail branch.

Solution is probably simple, but looks like I am unable to properly formulate the question to find solution to my problem.

So I have tree questions:

1. Why the `.fail` is never called, and what I need to change to make it work?
2. I basically understand difference between `.done` and `.then`. Both are called when promise is resolved, only that `.then` is chainable while done is not (If I'm correct). `.done` and `.fail` are usually paired as both have one callback, and `.then` has two. As I used two callbacks in `.done` why is second one called, since all callbacks in done are success callbacks?
3. Why reject doesn't call fail branch?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
var ajaxCall= function ($id) {
    return $.ajax({

        url: 'some_url'
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: packed,

        success: function (data) {

            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            switch (data.code) {
                case 200:
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                break;
                default:
                    deferred.reject(data);
                break;
            }

            return deferred.promise();

        },
        error: function () {
            $.Deferred().reject();
        }
    });
};

var successCall= function(){
 // code after both request completed with success;

};

var failureCall= function(){
// code after both request completed and if have error

};

$.when(ajaxCall(param1),ajaxCall(param2))
  .then( successCall, myFailure );
```

I have not tested but I read this kind a code in jQuery document at end of description in Examples section https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

> Execute the function myFunc when both ajax requests are successful, or
>   myFailure if either one has an error.
>
> $.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).then(myFunc, myFailure );

Comment: Your code is pretty same as mine, except that my two callback functions are inside `.then` block.